# golf ball tracking in Python/Opencv with different color balls

Tags: python, opencv

Just looking for some suggestions on how to approach the problem of golf ball tracking with different color balls.

I've explored using absdiff() to get the difference between frames to track the balls but it also picks up the player and club movement. Also, using HSV to pick up specific color balls but I want to be able to pick up most colors (white, yellow, orange, blue). Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

- 1. Do preprocess each frame

  ---

  - Apply `GaussianBlur`

    ```py
    gaussian_blurr = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (22, 22), 0)
    ```

    You can change the parameters, the above parameters are just examples.

    Assume below is your original frame:

    [image]

    Gaussian Blur will be:

    [image]

    We apply `GaussianBlur` for reducing noise and outliers.
  - Convert the frame to the HSV scale.

    ```py
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    ```

    [image]

    Converting `hsv` enable us to detect the ball in the current frame.
  - Apply `inRange` method:

    ```py
    greenLower = (29, 86, 6)
    greenUpper = (64, 255, 255)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
    ```

    [image]

    By defining our upper and lower boundaries, we locate the ball in the frame by declaring, 29 < Hue values < 64, 86 < Saturation < 255, 6 < Value < 255.
  - Apply `erode` and `dilate`:

    ```py
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
    ```

    [image]

  `erode` and `dilate` are commonly used for preprocessing images.

  `erode` removes pixels on object boundaries.

  `dilate` connecting areas that are separated by spaces. [source](https://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/idl/html_6.2/Eroding_and_Dilating_Image_Objects.html)
- 2. Find the center of the ball

---

- Find Contours

  ```py
  cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  ```

  Contours are used in shape detection and recognition. The output will be an array of ball location. We need the largest contours in the mask to find the center.

  ```py
  c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
  ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
  M = cv2.moments(c)
  center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
  ```

  `minClosingCircle` will cover the object with minimum area.

  `moments` will return the weighted area. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment)

  Updated: If you want to see the centroid of the ball add the following:

  ---

  ```py
  cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
  ```

  Result:

  [image]
- Now, if we combine all frames, the final will be:

---

- [image]
- Final with the centroid of the ball:

---

- [image]

Now, for different kinds of balls, you need to declare upper and lower bounds, as we declared `greenUpper` and `greenLower`. Then apply the steps starting from 1.

Full Code:

```py
import cv2
import imutils
import time

greenLower = (29, 86, 6)
greenUpper = (64, 255, 255)

vs = cv2.VideoCapture("input.mp4")
time.sleep(2.0)

while True:
    _, frame = vs.read()

    if frame is None:
        break

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    width, height = frame.shape[:2]
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    center = None

    if len(cnts) > 0:
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

        # To see the centroid clearly
        if radius > 10:
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (0, 255, 255), 5)
            cv2.imwrite("circled_frame.png", cv2.resize(frame, (int(height / 2), int(width / 2))))
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Why do you need the moments to get the center?  You have that from ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c). The moments would give the centroid of the white pixels and not necessarily the center of the circle. It would be a better answer if showed or linked to your full code. But nice approach. Your use of minEnclosingCircle() was a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the `moments`. I forgot to add the final frames with the centroid of the ball :)

Comment: I've updated the answer, the full code is added.

Comment: `@Ahmet` Thanks you

Comment: @Ahmet, I actually saw the write-up and youtube video for the example above and it works great with a green ball. But what if we don't know what color the ball is? What if the ball is white or yellow or blue, how would you handle that?

Comment: If you don't know the color of the ball, then you could use a semantic [segmentation approach](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tingwuwang/semantic_segmentation.pdf). However, the deep-learning approaches require `gpu` which I don't have. You need to create a network, train with ball samples. Then use the network for object tracking. I can't make a step-by-step explanation, due to `gpu` issue.