# OMR BubbleSheet Test Recognization

Tags: python, django, opencv, omr

I'm handling my last homework for the university in Spain (Business Adminstration), and I decided create a system that the Teacher insert the Exam correct answer, then download a model to give to the students do the exam, and after recieve the exams, he uploads it and the system compare the correct answers with the answers that the students did.

The model is this one:
answers sheet model

[image]

The model with correct answers: answer sheet correct:

[image]

Wrong answer exam: wrong answer exam:

[image]

I could develop the backend in Django, they can do everything before the test corrector.
Of course I tried multiple ways (Bubblesheet OMR on google and we have a lot of people doing the same test using the same example: https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/03/bubble-sheet-multiple-choice-scanner-and-test-grader-using-omr-python-and-opencv/ ), I found more examples, but the most closer one was : [Detect All Circles in an image (Optical Mark Recognition) using Python OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69499289/detect-all-circles-in-an-image-optical-mark-recognition-using-python-opencv) , but not worked in my example file.

Can someone help me please?

Here you have the three options. The Idea is that the teacher will upload all the PDF files, then is transformed into img (i did it using pdf2image), and then the corrector system loop in all the images/pdf correcting and given the scores of the students.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.